# preg_match php - независимый поиск

Tags: php, pcre

У меня есть строка в которой присутствуют переносы строк и табуляции. Возможно ли как-нибудь проверить данную строку независимо от этих символов?

Пример строки:

```
$str = "code 
        code";
```

Comment: уточните проблему, ибо пока что ее не видно. на крайний случай, вы всегда можете удалить из строки переносы строк и табуляции, после чего выполнить поиск

Comment: используйте ключ `m`(multiline) `/(code)/m`

Comment: вот список всех модификаторов шаблонов https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: @МихаилРебров спасибо